# Unable to connect android device to eclipse on linux system

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm unable to connect an android device to eclipse on the linux system using abd. I have created `51-android.rules` file in `root/etc/udev/rules.d` as follows:

```
SUBSYSTEM="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2821", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEMS="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2821",ATTRS{idProduct}=="19983" MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4" MODE="0666"
```

When I connect an android device to the linux system, the device isn't recognizable. Rather, I get ?????? as the device name.

Softwares installed:

- Ubuntu 10.04
- Eclipse Indigo
- Android 4.3

Comment: I think you mean Android 4.0.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

if ADB is in your $PATH. if not,

```
sudo ./adb kill-server
sudo ./adb start-server
```

From android-sdk/platform-tools.

Comment: I have already done that... But, it doesn't seem to help. The serial number of the device is shown as ??????

Answer (score 1):

You need two '=' after the SUBSYSTEM (ie. `SUBSYSTEM**==**"usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2821"`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file name is correct !

`/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.` (Contains . at the end)

You must add permission to this file so external application can gain privilege to access it by

```
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Detail Description about device configuration is [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)..